# Rejecting all the variables

Tags: r, logistic-regression

While doing the logistic regression  in R, all the p values came to be 1, rejecting all the assumptions. What would be the error?

```
# Build Logistic Model
logdown <- glm(classification ~ bp+bgr+bu+sod+pot+hemo+pcv+wc+rc, family = "binomial", data = down_train)
```

> Warning messages: 1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge  2: glm.fit:
>   fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

```
summary(logdown)

Call: glm(formula = classification ~ bp + bgr + bu + sod + pot + hemo
     pcv + wc + rc, family = "binomial", data = down_train) 

 Deviance Residuals: 
           Min             1Q         Median             3Q            Max  
 -0.0000231166  -0.0000000211   0.0000000000   0.0000000211   0.0000310084   

 Coefficients:
                   Estimate     Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|) 
(Intercept)     384.391182 1244660.587236       0        1 
bp                0.954292    5868.460874       0        1 
bgr               0.503592    1472.911453       0        1 
bu               -0.104507     857.081651       0        1
sod              -2.889344   10937.812900       0        1 
pot               7.801181   54746.963038       0        1 
hemo             -6.398532   25335.287408       0        1 
pcv              -1.060024    6935.366539       0        1 
wc                0.001903      25.199416       0        1 
rc               -6.043063   47852.993574       0        1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 85.9502503894332  on 61  degrees of freedom Residual deviance:
                0.0000000030718  on 52  degrees of freedom 
AIC: 20    
Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25
```

Comment: You can check this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5354/128897.

Comment: Hey your classification column is wrong. How can you have an intercept of 384.391182 when doing a logistic regression?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  It looks like you have very strong multicollinearity in your data.  The coefficient values are all right but the standard errors are enormous and residual deviance is tiny.  Remove variables from data, one-by-one, and see if it gets better at some point.